# Bash scripting: Using wildcard

Tags: bash, shell-scripting

I have two different folders.

The first one contains symlbolic links named with the names of my servers (for example: udcedpai101). 
The second one contains the inventory of my servers where the files are named with the server name at the beginning and ending with different paterns. (that's the reason I use the wildcard)

The inventory file name always begins with the name of the servers (for example: `udcedpai101-print_manifest.txt`, legpspai101-print_inventaire.txt, legpspai101.myhome.qc.ca-print_inventaire.txt). But they can ending differently.

Here's the command i'm running:

```
for i in `ls -l /etc/domain.conf | grep ^l | awk {'print $9'}`*; do
 ls -l "/var/opt/apache/htdocs/support/print_manifest/$i*"; 
done
```

(Partial) output ...

```
> /usr/local/coreutils/bin/ls: cannot access
> /var/opt/apache/htdocs/support/print_manifest/udcedcgi101*: No such file or directory /usr/local/coreutils/bin/ls: cannot access
> /var/opt/apache/htdocs/support/print_manifest/udcedcgi102*: No such file or directory /usr/local/coreutils/bin/ls: cannot access
> /var/opt/apache/htdocs/support/print_manifest/udcedcgi103*: No such file or directory
```

I'm trying to use a wildcard (*) in my command but it always returns an error stating that the file isn't there but I can view the file even though the file is there:

```
ls -l /var/opt/apache/htdocs/support/print_manifest/udcedcgi103*
-rw-r----- 1 TOTO TOTO 69455 Mar  9 00:00 /var/opt/apache/htdocs/support/print_manifest/udcedcgi103-print_manifest.txt
```

Your assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: What's the 9th value you're expecting? can you please display the output of `ls -l /etc/domain.conf | grep ^l`? Thanks.

Comment: lrwxr-xr-x  1 root sys    3 Jul 25  2014 udcedcgi101 -> dev/
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root sys    3 Jul 25  2014 udcedcgi102 -> dev/
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root sys    3 Jul 25  2014 udcedcgi103 -> dev/
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root sys    3 Jul 25  2014 udcedcgi104 -> dev/
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root sys    3 Jul 24  2014 udcedcgi105 -> dev/

Comment: the can actually end with HOSTNAME-print_manifest.txt, or HOSTNAME-print_inventory.txt. sometime, it could apen the hostname get the FQDN.  We do not succeed but thanks for your time. Any idea anybody else?

Answer (score 1):

[You should not be parsing the output from `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  Instead, try something like this:

```
for i in /etc/domain.conf/*; do
    test -L "$i" || continue  # skip if not a symlink
    ls -l "/var/opt/apache/htdocs/support/print_manifest/${i%%*/}"* 
done
```

The second problem is that the asterisk was in double quotes, so the shell was looking for `udcedcgi101*` literally, not as a wildcard to expand.

The `${i%%*/}` retrieves just the base name of the file, because the loop now iterates over full path names instead of relative paths within `/etc/domain.conf/`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the second quote in the `ls` within the loop to before the `*`

Change

```
ls -l "/var/opt/apache/htdocs/support/print_manifest/$i*";
```

to

```
ls -l "/var/opt/apache/htdocs/support/print_manifest/$i"*;
```

You probably don't need the quotes at all. Having the `*` inside the double quotes stops it being expanded.

Comment: While removing quotes appears to be safe in this individual case, missing quotes is one of the major sources of confusion and bugs in shell scripts. What if you change one of the paths in the future so that it does require quoting?